# how to use hover in objects in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, object, hover

I defined a object `useStyle` and called it in the component `SecondTest` defined background color, is it possible to add hover in the object `useStyle`

```
const useStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "red",
  };

function SecondTest() {
  return <div style={useStyle}>SecondTest go down</div>;
}

export default SecondTest;
```

Comment: Its not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use Radium React Library

```
import React from "react";
import Radium from "radium";

const style = {
  color: "#000000",
  ":hover": {
    color: "#ffffff"
  }
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  return <section style={style}>hello world</section>;
};

const MyStyledComponent = Radium(MyComponent);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyStyledComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it with events like `onMouseEnter` & `onMouseLeave` if you wish to use javascript to solve your issue. Easier way to do it would be just to give an element `className` like

`<section className='myClass'>hello world</section>`

and then just to add desired properties in your .css file which you can import in your component or globally.

```
.myClass {
  color: #000000;
}

.myClass:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

It is not possible to add hover with in-line styles.